# how to call DB2 functions in Informatica ETL?

Tags: db2, etl, informatica-powercenter

How to call DB2 functions in Informatica ETL?

Only used views in ETL before, have no idea how to do so for the functions, anyone got any idea?

Comment: Did you check if the Stored Procedure transformation can be used to invoke functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarekGrzenkowicz is correct, it is the same as envoke stored procedures.